# setup postfix or equiv to only forward to new address

Tags: postfix, vps, email-server, mail-forwarding

Is there a dead easy way to set up an MTA to only redirect incoming mail

```
user@mydomain.com -> myCheapGmailAccount@gmail.com
```

Yes, I've tried various postfix guides but I'm lost in configuration.

Host: fresh debian

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set your `virtual_alias_maps` to a file:

```
postconf -e virtual_alias_maps=hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

Then you put in the file:

```
user@mydomain.com myCheapGmailAccount@gmail.com
```

you need to active the change now:

```
postmap hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

That is all.